# Ruby - While loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop

How can I say to my program to make the sum of the numbers in input after read the word "end"?
Like this:

```
    a=gets.to_s
    b="end"
    n=0
    while a=a.to_s
      n=a.to_i+n                             
      if a.to_s==b 
      #If I enter "end" the while loop stop and It prints the sum of the numbers typed until now
        break
        puts n
      end
    end
```

I'm new here, sorry about my English but I'm still learning.

Comment: Could you give some example input?

Comment: A simple example would help. Define a string and assign it to a variable. For example, `str = "One tends 99 to end 23 cats 4 dogs -9"`. Then show what number (a sum) you want returned. Please do this by editing your question rather than doing so in a comment. You need to specify where you want the summation to begin, after the first instance of  the string `"end"` (in the word `"tends"`, in my example) or after the first word `"end"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [Kernel#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) to obtain a string from the user.

```
str = gets
```

Suppose this results in the following value for `str`.

```
str #=> "One tends 99 to end 23 cats 4 dogs -9\n"
```

`gets` returns a string, so there is no need to convert it to a string (as you have done). `str` will end with a newline character (`"\n"`). In some applications that is not wanted so it is stripped off using [String#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) (`str = gets.chomp`). Here the presence of the newline is of no concern, so there's no need to remove it.

Next we need to locate the first instance of the the string `"end"` as an offset into the string. For that we use the method [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-index).

```
idx = str.index('end')
  #=> 5
```

which is the index of the `"e"` in `"tends"`.

If `str` did not contain a substring `"end"`, `idx` would equal `nil`. Since `idx` is here not `nil` we need to sum the string representations of integers in the substring that follows `"end"`.

```
 s = str[idx+"end".size..-1]
   #=> "s 99 to end 23 cats 4 dogs -9\n"
```

We can extract the string representations of integers with the method [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan), employing a regular expression.

```
arr = s.scan(/-?\d+/)
  #=> ["99", "23", "4", "-9"]
```

The regular expression reads, "optionally (the question mark) match a minus sign followed by one or more (the plus) digits".

We can then convert these to integers and add them up with method [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum), which made its debut in Ruby v2.4.

```
arr.sum { |ss| ss.to_i }
  #=> 117
```

We can write this more compactly as follows.

```
arr.sum(&:to_i)
  #=> 117
```

To support versions of Ruby earlier than 2.4 we could use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

```
arr.reduce(0) { |tot, st| tot + st.to_i }
  #=> 117
```

We can put all this together in a method.

```
def total_after_first_end(str)
  idx = str.index('end')
  return nil if idx.nil?
  str[idx+"end".size..-1].scan(/-?\d+/).sum(&:to_i)
end

str = gets
  #=> "One tends 99 to end 23 cats 4 dogs -9\n"
total_after_first_end(str)
  #=> 117
```

Now lets suppose it's not the first substring `"end"` that marks the beginning of the sum, but it's the first word `"end"`. To make that adjustment we need only change the regular expression slightly.

```
idx = str.index(/\bend\b/)
  #=> 16
```

`"\b"` is a [word boundary](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) (search "word boundary").

```
s = str[idx+"end".size..-1]
  #=> " 23 cats 4 dogs -9\n"
arr = s.scan(/-?\d+/)
  #=> ["23", "4", "-9"]
arr.sum(&:to_i)
  #=> 18
```